# R-Keras - How come val_loss is not plotting

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras

My first time playing with Keras. I tried to run the model and see the loss  and accuracy. For some reason, its not plotting the loss for `val_loss`.

My code:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu", input_shape = dim(train.X)[[2]]) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")


model %>% compile (
  optimizer = "rmsprop", #configuring optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 0.001)
  loss = "binary_crossentropy", #custom loss -> loss_binary_crossentropy
  metrics = c("accuracy") #metric_binary_accuracy
) 

history <- model %>% fit(
  train.X,
  train.Y,
  epochs = 100,
  batch_size = 64,
  validation_data = list(x_val, y_val)
)
```

My results:
[image]

I would really appreciate if someone can explain to me why the val_loss function is not plotting.

Comment: Hi, there's no way of knowing how you split `x_val, y_val` nor to reproduce your example, because you did not include the dataset and pre-processing steps. I suggest you try to inspect the metrics data frame: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/tfruns/reference/view_run_metrics.html and go upstream from there. Here's DataCamp tutorial you may want to consult: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/keras-r-deep-learning

Comment: pls show the actual `plot` commands

Comment: I have split the data 90/10. The plot came up when I ran the fit() function.